# Number of characters that fit in NSTextView

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, nstextview

*Note: This question is for a MacOS app and not for iOS*

---

I have a business requirement to convert this amazing iOS custom text view([ReadMoreTextView](https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView)) to macOS(AppKit). However I am finding it difficult to convert it. I was hoping it would be easy since both `UITextView` and `NSTextView` use `NSTextContainer`, `NSLayoutManager` and `NSTextStorage`. But it seems like they behave differently on both platforms.

I need to calculate the number of characters or character range that is visible on the `NSTextView`. I am trying to use the following method but it is always returning the complete character range instead of visible character range(actual text length instead of visible text length). I couldn't find any other method in layout manager which can help on this. Please let me know if you have any pointers on this.

Here is the code:

```
extension NSLayoutManager {
    func characterRangeThatFits(textContainer container: NSTextContainer) -> NSRange {
        //this is the current maximum number of lines
        //container.maximumNumberOfLines = 3

        var rangeThatFits = self.glyphRange(for: container)
        rangeThatFits = self.characterRange(forGlyphRange: rangeThatFits, actualGlyphRange: nil)
        return rangeThatFits
    }
}
```

Answers in Swift and Objective C are welcome.

***Update:***

Please ignore any scrolling on the textview since I am disabling all types of scrolling. My intention is to have a view with *"... More"* button at the end of it then on tap of it the view gets expanded. For this reason `NSTextField` based solution is also welcome if we can find visible characters in that.

Comment: @rmaddy, I am looking for answers in Objective C of Swift. Please don't remove it. I will miss answers in Objective C as this question is not restricted to swift.

Comment: Tags represent what the question is about. Your question isn't about the Objective-C language even if you will accept such answers. You posted Swift code so your question is about Swift and you need people that understand Swift to see your question.

Comment: @rmaddy, ok. I am only worried experienced Objective C developers will miss this question since it is not tagged with it. Hoping some experienced developer may have already done this in their project in the past since this feature is present in App Store and Facebook iOS apps.

Comment: Just to let any future reader know. I gave up on this. Below code from Charles works only if used it at a later point of time after the view is displayed. The first time it always gives a character range more than it can display(and many time after that it gives wrong one). If anyone was able to convert "ReadMoreTextView" mentioned above to macOS, please comment here. It might help future readers.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the visible portion of the `NSTextView` using its `visibleRect` method. From there, you just need to get the text range that falls within that rect. So, if your view supports vertical scrolling only, something like this should work:

```
let visRect = textView.visibleRect

let layoutManager = textView.layoutManager!
let container = textView.textContainer!

let glyphRange = layoutManager.glyphRange(forBoundingRect: visRect, in: container)
let charRange = layoutManager.characterRange(forGlyphRange: glyphRange, actualGlyphRange: nil)
```

Be aware that if your `NSTextView` supports horizontal scrolling rather than just vertical, you'll have to do a little more work than this, since you'll possibly be looking at a non-contiguous block of text. In that case, you'll have to get a bunch of smaller ranges for each visible line fragment instead of just grabbing the whole range like this.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I just tried this for my textview and got range as `{0, 384}` whereas actual visible character count was only `300`. Is there any padding I need to subtract from `visibleRect` to get exact count? I am trying to append "... More" at this location and hence the issue.

Comment: By the way, please ignore any scrolling since by default I am disabling all scrolling on the textview. Hence the need for adding a more button.

Comment: @adev Are you taking newline characters into account? Also keep in mind that since this is an `NSRange`, it's counting UTF-16 code units, so any emojis or other non-BMP characters are going to count as more than one.

Comment: @adev Oh, one other thing; this will include characters that are only partially visible, so for your purposes you will probably want to check the rect for the last line and subtract it if it's not entirely within `visRect`.

Comment: I wouldn't have new line characters in my case. So that can be ignored. Could you please let me know how we can check if text is partially visible? and how can we calculate its rect? Appreciate your quick response.

Comment: @adev Like I said, just get the rect of the last line from `NSLayoutManager`, and see if it extends below the bottom of `visibleRect`.

Comment: Thanks, I tried that and it is still giving me more characters than that can be fitted on the textview. I will wait to see if anyone has cracked this issue or has a component similar to https://github.com/ilyapuchka/ReadMoreTextView in MacOS

Comment: I think you may need to take into account the NSTextView's textContainerOrigin. Try offsetting the rect you'll pass into layoutManager.glyphRange by the point you get back from that value.

Comment: @Matt, I have tried that and still there are extra two lines of characters based on this range calculation `rect = rect.offsetBy(dx: textContainerOrigin.x, dy: textContainerOrigin.y)
        rect = rect.insetBy(dx: textContainerInset.width, dy: textContainerInset.height)` I guess I am still missing something. Tried to inset `lineFragmentPadding` too and still doesn't help.